# Spring autowiring bean with mixed constructor

Tags: java, spring

I have two beans like this:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
class A {
    A(int number, B anotherBean) {
         //...
    }
}

@Component
class B {
     //..
}
```

How can I build A and have B autowired? If I use new I won't get anotherBean's value, if I use autowiring I won't get number's value.

**Edit:** The number is calculated at runtime, so I can't use @Value like answers suggested.

Comment: Just put `@Autowired` on the constructor. Or if you are using the `BeanFactory`/`ApplicationContext` to obtain a reference to `A` just use the `getBean(String name, Object args...)` to obtain it. As args pass the calculated value and the `B` object. You might want to put this in a factory that way you could wire `B` into the factory and have a factory method taking the `number` which in turn creates an instance of `A`.

Comment: Just putting autowired doesn't work becouse the number is not a spring managed property/bean. Using getBean(..) would work but this way the caller would have an unnecessary dependency for B for the sole purpose of using A. Making a factory can be a solution, I never thought about it. If I won't find any way without creating a separate class I go with the factory, thanks.

Comment: Autowiring will work but only when you use also `getBean` you would then only need to pass the `number` argument. The reference for `B` would be automatically resolved.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. If I autowire A's constructor and try to instantiate A with getBean("a", 1) I get the following exception: Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities). I'm using spring 3.2, perhaps it's a 4.x feature?

Answer (score 1):

I found this question today looking for an answer myself. After some consideration, here's a solution I think I'm going with. Basically I'm baking the factory method into the bean's class. This has the advantage of keeping the 'internal' dependencies (B in this example) all inside the 'A' class, and hidden from the caller, while still allowing prototype creation using a caller's runtime value. And it doesn't require yet another class file just for a factory method.

```
public class A {

  private A (int number, B otherBean) {
  ...
  }

  @Configuration
  public static class BeanConfig {

    @Autowired
    private B otherBean;

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public A makeA(int number) {
      return new A(number, otherBean);
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can request a prototype bean instance while providing only the runtime value:

```
applicationContext.getBean(A.class, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `@Value`and inject the number's value via property. Your `ClassA` should look something like

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
class A {

    @Autowired
    A(@Value("${some.property}")int number, B anotherBean) {
       //...
    }
}
```

**Edit** *(post additional condition of runtime value for number)*

You can fetch the bean from *[BeanFactory.getBeans](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.Class-)* method as correctly pointed out by [M.Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) in comments.

Comment: What if the value is calculated at runtime?

Comment: please see comments from Deinum; which I included in my answer

Comment: check the answer to that comment please.

Answer (score -2):

You need to annotate the desired constructor-to-be-used as @Autowired, among other ways you can find with a Google search. As for your issue with 'number', there are ways to use annotations to set parameter values as well, also not difficult to find with a Google search.

Comment: So because I don't spoon feed you code for something you haven't tried, I get downvoted. Awesome.