# Spring: Mixing Autowired fields and constructor arguments in a base class

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, dependency-injection, constructor

Basically, I want to make this code work:

```
@Component
abstract class MyBaseClass(val myArg: MyArgClass) {
  @Autowired
  private lateinit var myInjectedBean: MyInjectedBean

  fun useBothArgAndBean()
}

class MyConcreteClass(myArg: MyArgClass) : MyBaseClass(myArg)

val myConcreteClass = MyConcreteClass(obtainMyArgClass())
myConcreteClass.useBothArgAndBean()
```

So I have a base class with one argument in the constructor and another argument injected from the Spring context. Currently, such a setup is not possible because Spring tries to inject also `MyArgClass` from context and because there's no such bean (it's constructed manually) it fails on "no matching bean".

The question is how to make this scenario work. Note that I cannot use the factory-method solution mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58790893/13015027 because I need to directly call `MyBaseClass` constructor from `MyConcreteClass` constructor. Perhaps there's a trick on how to avoid that or how to force Spring not to try to inject into the base constructor or ...?

Comment: Usually, if I can't pass arguments to the constractor, I use no arguments constructor and  initialize object with required arguments after allocation. Maybe you can use MyBaseClass and MyConcreteClass no arguments constructors. And then add `public void init(MyArgClass)` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a quite confusing setup there, and I am not sure that you are fully aware how injection by Spring works. You can

- either create a class on your own, using its constructor, or
- you can let Spring create the class and inject everything, and you don't call the constructor.

When you call the constructor, Spring will not magically inject some parts of your class, just because it has seemingly the right annotations. The variable `myInjectedBean` will just be null.

If you want to have the ability to create the class on your own using the constructor, you should not use field injection, because you would obviously not have any possibility to initialize the field.

Then your classes `MyBaseClass` and `MyConcreteClass` would look like this:

```
abstract class MyBaseClass(
  val myArg: MyArgClass,
  private val myInjectedBean: MyInjectedBean
) {

  fun useBothArgAndBean()
}

class MyConcreteClass(myArg: MyArgClass, myInjectedBean: MyInjectedBean) : MyBaseClass(myArg, myInjectedBean)
```

Now, as already suggested by @Sam, you can have `myInjectedBean` be injected while providing `myArg` manually by writing another component that can completely be created by Spring, because it will only autowire `myInjectedBean` while `myArg` is provided as argument for a factory method:

```
@Component
class MyFactory(val myInjectedBean: MyInjectedBean) {
    fun createMyConcreteClass(myArg: MyArgClass) = 
        MyConcreteClass(myArg, myInjectedBean)
}
```

Then in a class, where you have an injected `myFactory: MyFactory` you can just call `myFactory.createMyConcreteClass(myArg)` and you obtain a new `MyConcreteClass` that has an injected `myInjectedBean`.

Comment: Actually, my use case is a little bit more complex and I describe it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73532777/spring-generic-class-with-autowired-dependencies. I just thought that abstracting and simplifying the problem would bring more attention which it did :-) Basically, I would like MyArgClass also to be injected by Spring but it's not possible because it's of a generic type that is erased in the time Spring sets up the application context.

Comment: But from what you say my efforts of mixing inheritance and DI in the base class are futile because I can't at the same time call the base class constructor (from the concrete class) and have the beans injected into the base class, right?

Comment: Yes, you got that right.

Answer (score 1):

I think you still do need some sort of factory. It would pass both the bean and the additional arguments to the `MyConcreteClass` constructor, and would look like this:

```kotlin
@Component
class MyFactory(val myInjectedBean: MyInjectedBean) {
    fun getMyConcreteClass(myArg: MyArgClass) = 
        MyConcreteClass(myArg, myInjectedBean)
}
```

If using that approach, none of the other classes except `MyInjectedBean` would need to be registered with Spring.

In fact, it's a little surprising to me that you currently have `MyBaseClass` annotated with `@Component`. What do you expect that to do, and does it work?